# Setting styles of page numbers for chapter pages and normal pages

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, titlesec

I have the following formatting requirements for my page numbering:

1. For chapter pages, centered on the bottom (half an inch from bottom edge of the paper)
2. For normal pages, right justified on the top-right corner (half an inch from the top edge and half an inch from the right edge if the paper)

Is there any way to do this with only `titlesec`?

**Edit 1:** I am not sure how my code works but here's what I've tried so far. Am I using it properly?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\newpagestyle{main}{\sethead{}{}{\thepage}}
\pagestyle{main}
```

It works fine but what if I want to place the page number on the right corner of the ToC and bibliography too? I feel like I'm not doing it properly.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What have you tried so far? Please show us your compilable tex code ...

Answer (score 0):

Use `\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{<style name>}` to change the page numbering style of a Chapter page.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib} %for bibliography
@article{label1,
  title={Any title},
  author={Name},
  journal={Journal},
  volume={1},
  number={1},
  pages={1000},
  year={2022},
  publisher={Publisher}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec} %pagestyles option in necessary
\newpagestyle{main}{%
    \sethead%
        {}{}{\thepage}%
}
\newpagestyle{chap}{%
    \setfoot%
        {}{\thepage}{}%
}

\usepackage{duckuments} %for dummy text

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{main}
\tableofcontents

\pagestyle{main}

\chapter{One}
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{chap}

\duckument

\chapter{Cite}
\cite{label1}

\duckument

\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{main}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

TOC page:

[image]

Bibliography Page:

[image]

Note: Always try to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). The absence of an MWE discourages answering.